# how to insert sum()

Tags: insert

I wonder what query I can use to insert the total sum from table1 with the same id to table 2?

```
 table1
 id    total
 101    2
 101    3
 102    3
 102    5

table2
id    total
101   5
102   8
```

this is my query

```
$query = mysql_query("Insert into table2(id,total)
select id, sum(total) from table1 group by id") or die(mysql_error());
```

I got this error

```
"Duplicate entry '144' for key 'PRIMARY'"
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Did you truncate `table2` before running the insert?

Comment: Isn't error clear enough? You already have an entry for id 144 it seems.

Comment: what do you mean add language tag? @yu hao

Comment: Add the tag of the programming language, e.g, `php`, `javascript`, `mysql`, etc.

Comment: i still don't get how to add the total with the same id.

Comment: i'm using html, php, and mysql